# SQL with ASP Classic (Syntax error in FROM clause.)

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I am recieveing the error below when I try to run this SQL, no idea why and been stuck at it for a while now, can any of you spot the problem

```
 Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80040e14'

 Syntax error in FROM clause.

 /student/s0190204/wip/group-add.asp, line 54
```

It says the error is on line 54 which i marked out. However the problem is likely from the SQL.

```
comd.ActiveConnection=conx
    set userRs=server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
    groupcheck="SELECT * FROM Group"
    54> userRs.Open groupcheck,conx, adOpenkeyset, AdLockOptimistic
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: As a note, I personally avoid using table names that are reserved keywords. It's not that many words. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP` is a [reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335) in most RDBMS.  Surround it in square brackets to use it as a table or column identifier in MS Access, thereby distinguishing it from `GROUP BY`.

```
groupcheck="SELECT * FROM [Group]"
```

Comment: Of course! I had the same problem with 'Like' earlier so I should of spotted it really. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`Group` is a keyword in most database. so use another name for your table

or you can use the query as `SELECT * FROM [Group]`

To learn more about the reserved keywords in sql server,

[Reserved Keywords List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507(v=sql.80).aspx)